# phpをwindows10でコマンドプロンプトから実行したい

Tags: php, windows-10, コマンドプロンプト

sample.phpをwindows10でコマンドプロンプトから実行したいです。

画像のように `php sample.php` でファイルを指定して実行するとエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
Could not open input file: sample.php
```

`php -v` のようにオプションだけを指定して実行したら、期待通りに返ってきます。

また、Apacheを起動してWebブラウザにはsample.phpの実行結果を出せています。

[image: コマンドプロンプト実行結果]

Comment: この記事のように、スクリプトファイルをフルパスで指定してみてはどうでしょう？ [PHPコマンドライン実行 - PHP インストールからコマンドライン実行まで](https://qiita.com/AoiLaurent/items/445e5dd47a4212e81bbe#php%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C)

Answer (score 1):

まずは sample.php の保存場所を確認してください。`C:\php-7.4.13\` の下に保存されていますか？
Apache から見えているということは、例えば `C:\Apache24\htdocs\` の下にあったりしませんか？

**方法1**

保存場所が確認できたら、コマンドプロンプトを開いた後に該当のフォルダまで `cd` コマンドで移動します。(ここでは仮に `C:\Apache24\htdocs` とします)

```
C:\> cd c:\Apache24\htdocs
```

フォルダを移動したら、`dir` コマンドで PHP ファイルが存在するかを確認してください。

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs> dir

  ... フォルダに存在するファイルの一覧が表示される
```

PHP ファイルがあるのを確認したら、`php` コマンドの引数に渡して実行してみてください。

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs> php sample.php
```

**方法2**

ファイルの保存場所は予め確認しておいた上で、コメントでも指摘のある通りファイルのフルパスを指定して実行する方法もあります。

```
C:\php-7.4.13> php C:\Apache24\htdocs\sample.php
```

Comment: C:\Apache24\htdocs\の下にphpを置いていました。教えて頂いたように、そこに移動してみると実行できました。ご回答頂き、ありがとうございました。